# Why does my primary partition not reflect the total disk space?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I remotely ssh'd and resized my primary partition with parted (rebooted as well and updated /etc/fstab) to give it more space.

Why on earth is my primary ext4 partition not reflecting the free space?

```
~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  3.5M  197M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       7.8G  7.5G     0 100% /
tmpfs           999M     0  999M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           999M     0  999M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/0

~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x010920b9

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux
```

Any ideas? I must have forgotten something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Execute  `parted` and then  `print free`. This will print free space of your system.